# jqplot w/ both remote and local data series

Tags: ajax, jqplot

I've seen examples of, and written, jqplots where the series data is either supplied directly or comes from a remote source (via ajax).  I do not see how to have a single plot with both kinds of sources; that is, one series with the data provided, and another which uses the ajaxDataRenderer.  Other than getting the remote data outside of jqplot (so it could be passed as a local series), is there any way of having both types of series in a single plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved passing a list of 2 series: the first with the url needed for the ajax call, the other with the data for the second series.  Then, defining the `series` element for the plot, the first containing the options needed for the ajax plot, the second with the options needed for that plot.  Then, within the `dataRenderer` routine, each of the series can be handled appropriately.